# Proof by induction - Volume integrals

Tags: integration, induction

I want to prove the formula
$$ ∫_0^w∫_0^w∫_0^w 1\,dx\,dy\,dz= w^3   $$

I've done:

Let w = 1. 
$$ ∫_0^1∫_0^1∫_0^11 \,dx\,dy\,dz= 1^3 $$

RHS:
$$ 1^3=1 $$
LHS: 
\begin{align*}
∫_0^1∫_0^1∫_0^11 \,dx\,dy\,dz&= ∫_0^1∫_0^1[x]_0^1  \,dy\,dz\\
&=∫_0^1∫_0^11 \,dy\,dz\\
&=∫_0^1[y]_0^1\,  dz\\
&=∫_0^11 \,dz= [z]_0^1\\
&=1
\end{align*}
LHS = RHS ∴ The equation is true for w = 1.

Let w = k
$$∫_0^k∫_0^k∫_0^k1 \,dx\,dy\,dz= k^3$$
Let w = k+1
$$∫_0^{(k+1)}∫_0^{(k+1)}∫_0^{(k+1)} 1 \,dx\,dy\,dz=(k+1)^3$$

I can't see how to factor in the k equation into the $k+1$ equation

Comment: Induction is irrelevant here.  What is $\int_a^b 1~\text{d}x$?

Comment: Induction is irrelevant here; what if $w=\pi$?

Comment: If you had taken the effort you put into proving the "base case" ($w=1$) and instead applied it directly to the original formula to be proved, you'd be done by now.

Answer (score 0):

It's really because you've asked for it...

Let have the induction hypothesis $P(k)="\int_0^k dt=k\text{ and }\int_k^{k+1}dt=1"$

The induction step is then

$\begin{array}{ll|l}
\int_0^{k+1}\int_0^{k+1}\int_0^{k+1}dxdydz= & \int_0^{k}\int_0^{k}\int_0^{k}dxdydz+\int_0^{k}\int_0^{k}\int_k^{k+1}dxdydz\ + & k^3+k^2\\
&\int_0^{k}\int_k^{k+1}\int_0^{k}dxdydz+\int_0^{k}\int_k^{k+1}\int_k^{k+1}dxdydz\ + & k^2+k\\
&\int_k^{k+1}\int_0^{k}\int_0^{k}dxdydz+\int_k^{k+1}\int_0^{k}\int_k^{k+1}dxdydz\ + & k^2+k\\
&\int_k^{k+1}\int_k^{k+1}\int_0^{k}dxdydz+\int_k^{k+1}\int_k^{k+1}\int_k^{k+1}dxdydz & k+1\\
&& k^3+3k^2+3k+1\end{array}$

$=(k+1)^3$